# Package pdftex.def Error: File `./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, epstopdf

I read all the previous questions on the automatic `epstopdf` conversion which does not work and none answers my own problem though I am in a seemingly identical case with some of the previously reported cases.

I use TexStudio 2.8.6 on a Mac 10.7.5.
I have made a simple test case `document.tex` trying to load an `essai.eps` file in it. It does not work :

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <essai.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2014-12-04 13:00:47
(epstopdf)                    size: 48317 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=./essai-eps-converted-to.pd
f essai.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 154.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf essai.eps)...executed
.

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
```

I have tried to add `-shell-escape` or `--shell-escape` (is it 1 or 2 dashes? both are mentioned in the different posts), i also added `usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}`. Nothing works. However the problem is ***internal*** to TexStudio since running `pdflatex document.tex` on the command line works perfectly and produces the `.pdf` images I need.

Therefore I guess that TexStudio is trying to write the file in a strange place and possibly in a place where it is not authorized to write because a global search on the whole hard drive does not find the file.

What is wrong with TexStudio ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you show the first line in the `.log` file that is produced with the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

The `.log` shows:

```
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf essai.eps)...executed
```

But the file does not seem to be generated, thus the conversion failed.
Try to do it manually, the command is given above. Option `--debug` gives
more hints, what might went wrong:

```
epstopdf --debug --outfile=./essai-eps-converted-to.pdf essai.eps
```

The Perl script `epstopdf` calls ghostscript for the actual conversion from EPS to PDF. A further calls it directly:

```
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop essai.eps
```